# JCE 2.5 is missing its toolbar

Tags: joomla, toolbar, joomla-content-editor, joomla3.9

I am using JCE 2.5 with Joomla 3.9.8 Stable.

I have 2 user groups; one is a super user and other is frontend user.

**The editor is loading fine for super users, but for frontend users the toolbar of editor is missing**. It was working well and suddenly disappeared, not sure what was the contributing factor.

I have checked all the settings of editor and user group and everything is fine. The editor is enable and set as the default. I also tried adding JCE editor under the basic settings of the user but nothing helps.

This is how it loads:
[image]

When I click on the "Toggle Editor", it just hides the grey section meant to load toolbar below is the image.
[image]

Comment: Try reinstalling the latest version of JCE Editor over the top of the existing version, check all the JCE plugins are enabled in Plugin Manager. Check editor settings in Global Configuration and also for each user in User Manager.

Comment: I have tried this all but nothing works, although JCE loads fine for superuser logged in on frontend but not for manager or registered users.

Comment: Try checking the JCE Editor Profiles. In particular, which user groups are assigned and whether the profile is enabled for back-end and/or front-end.

Comment: I uninstalled JCE completely and then re installed new version then I made some changes to editor profiles just randomly assigning and unassigning users and user groups, somehow it started working like miracle. Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Why not post your Joomla question on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange?  You've received two successful resolutions in the past, why go else where?